# Update field with partial match

Tags: filemaker

i have a parsing calculation in a field called "output" that looks at another field (called "parser") and updates "output" with a portion of the data from "parser" (specifically, The data is "XCX0001-user", the calculation looks for "-user" and then updates the output field with "XCX001").

Here is what I have so far:

```
If ( FilterValues ( layout::parser ; "-user" )  ; 
Left ( layout::parser ; Position ( layout::parser ; "-" ; 1 ; 1 ) -1 ) 
; 0 )
```

So if the field doesnt have the "-user" portion, it will print a '0', not "XCX001". Though it doesnt look like "Filter Values" looks for partial matches. Any way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FilterValues()` does not do what you think it does (see the [help](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/17/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Ffiltervalues.html%23) for more).

To test if your field contains the string `"-user"`, you can use =

```
PatternCount ( YourField ; "-user" )
```

or =

```
Position ( YourField ; "-user" ; 1 ; 1  )
```

as your test expression. Alternatively, if the string is always at the end, you could test for =

```
Right ( YourField ; 5  ) =  "-user"
```

Comment: I see, that makes sense, but its still not working. I still get "0" when i swap out the two bits of code.

Comment: If `PatternCount ( YourField ; "-user" )` returns false (i.e. 0), then your field does not contain the string `"-user"`. Check your data.

Comment: Welcome back @michael.hor257k! The XSLT tag missed your presence!

Comment: @Parfait Thanks. We'll see.